# How can I keep bundler from comlaining about sys-proctable gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I can't install sys-proctable with bundle. It won't stop complaining even though it's installed:

```
$ gem install sys-proctable --platform universal-linux
Fetching: sys-proctable-0.9.2-universal-linux.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sys-proctable-0.9.2-universal-linux
1 gem installed

$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Could not find sys-proctable-0.9.2 in any of the sources

$ bundle install --platform universal-linux
Unknown switches '--platform'

$ bundle config build.sys-proctable --platform univeral-linux

$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Could not find sys-proctable-0.9.2 in any of the sources

$ bundle install --without production
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Could not find sys-proctable-0.9.2 in any of the sources

$ grep proctable Gemfile

$  rails console
You have requested:
  pg = 0.12.2

The bundle currently has pg locked at 0.12.2.
Try running `bundle update pg`
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-5.1 dumbopc 1.7.17(0.262/5/3) 2012-10-19 14:39 i686 Cygwin
```

Gemfile: http://pastebin.com/Fre28yTp

`gem list --local`: http://pastebin.com/yP0sbHF2

Tried adding `gem 'sys-proctable', '~>0.9.2', :git => 'git://github.com/djberg96/sys-proctable.git'` to the Gemfile, but that didn't work:

```
$ bundle install
Updating git://github.com/djberg96/sys-proctable.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'sys-proctable (~> 0.9.2) ruby' in git://github.com/djberg96/sys-proctable.git (at master).
Source contains 'sys-proctable' at: 0.9.2
```

Comment: Can you show your Gemfile?

Comment: Do you use RVM/rbenv?

Comment: paste `gem list --local`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't tell for sure unless you show your `Gemfile` but it seems that the gem you are asking for is `sys-proctable-0.9.2` instead of `sys-proctable`,

It is true you will need to use `bundle config build.sys-proctable --platform univeral-linux` before installing to get the desired response, but the gem name is `sys-proctable`.

**Edit**

Following this issue https://github.com/djberg96/sys-proctable/issues/24 it seems you can check out if you can actually require it in `irb` and if so just work with it, regarding the annoying messages you can follow and require it's path from a local directory or directly from their `git` repository.

either as `gem 'sys-proctable', :git => 'git://github.com/djberg96/sys-proctable.git'`

or

`gem 'sys-proctable', :path => 'path/to/gem/inside/project'`

Comment: Ok will try the others. RE irb, what does this mean: `$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'sys-proctable'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sys-proctable`

Comment: that it can not find the gem, but try to do first, `require 'rubygems'` and only then `sys-proctable`

Comment: Ok `require 'rubygems'
=> false`, but `require 'sys-proctable'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sys-proctable`, `require 'sys-proctable-univeral-linux'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sys-proctable-univeral-linux`, `require 'sys-proctable-0.9.2-universal-linux'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sys-proctable-0.9.2-universal-linux`

Comment: I tried adding `gem 'sys-proctable', :path => '/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sys-proctable-0.9.2-universal-linux'` to my Gemfile, and it gave this error: `Could not find gem 'sys-proctable (>= 0) ruby' in source at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sys-proctable-0.9.2-universal-linux.`

Comment: I tried `gem 'sys-proctable', :git => 'git://github.com/djberg96/sys-proctable.git'` in the Gemfile and it gave this error: `Could not find gem 'sys-proctable (>= 0) ruby' in git://github.com/djberg96/sys-proctable.git (at master).`

Comment: You have to require it like this 
`require 'sys/proctable'`
`include Sys`, as it says in the README
https://github.com/djberg96/sys-proctable/blob/master/README

Comment: That worked: `irb(main):002:0> require 'sys/proctable'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> include Sys
=> Object`

Comment: glad we figured this one out :-)

Comment: Yeah, but the 'bundle install' still won't work, and I still can't run 'rails console'. I had to follow the steps in that issue you posted, download the source, run 'gem build', and install it in 'vendor/gems' to get 'bundle install' to continue. https://github.com/djberg96/sys-proctable/issues/24 Now it complains about another :production gem, 'pg', when it should be ignoring those.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `rm Gemfile.lock` then run `bundle install`.

The gem in your Gemfile should look as follows:
`gem 'sys-proctable', :git => 'git://github.com/djberg96/sys-proctable.git'`

**Extra Help:**

I hit this issue when I tried migrating over to jRuby. If you did the same, and your deploying to Heroku, make these edits as well:

In your Gemfile remove the `sqlite3` gem and the `pg` gem. Replace them with these:

`gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'` 
`gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter'`

Comment: It was a problem with Bundler, which could not find the correct version under Cygwin. I reported as an issue to Bundler. https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/2341. I also found Guard-Spork was requiring it with `gem --dependency sys-proctable --reverse-dependencies`.